# Why google translate is not working in innerHTML js

Tags: javascript, html

my code:

```
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'sticky';
  div.id = 'google_translate_element'
  div.innerHTML = '<div id="google_translate_element"></div>';
  function googleTranslateElementInit() { new google.translate.TranslateElement({ 
  pageLanguage: "pl" }, "google_translate_element"); }
  document.body.innerHTML = '<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"> 
  </script>';
  document.body.appendChild(div);
```

when im trying add this html to website google translate is not working.
Any one have idea?

Comment: your code writes out `<div class="sticky" id="google_translate_element"><div id="google_translate_element"></div></div>`, also you have line breaks in your string for script tag which is a syntax error

Comment: additionally, you have no text on the page to translate

Comment: ok now im breaking lines and I have no red underlines it still is not working

Comment: I wanna inject this code to page, where is text to translate